# How to shift UIViews and put a new UIView programmatically with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I've a layout with my data, but depending on data I need change the location of views. I wants put a UIView (UILabel, UITextField...) at top of screen and shift the layout to down, but I don't know how to do this, I saw some docs and tutorials but not helps me. I made my screen with storyboard.

This is original screen:

[image]

This is that I want:

[image]

My storyboard:

[image]

Comment: You should use a tableview for this and insert a row at the top when needed.

Comment: This is a good ideia but in this case I want to add a new UIView

Comment: And `UITableViewCell` is also a `UIView` and you can put your view inside cells' content view. Or if you want to add your view at the top of your `tableView`, you can also set your view to `tableHeaderView` property of your `tableView`

Comment: I don't have a UITableView, instead I have Views and StackView, like shows the 3th image. I appreciate the hint but this project is being done so.

Comment: Sorry, was confused by the text `Table View` on the screenshot. This (3rd) screenshot could be more usefull if subviews of the stack view would be shown. I've put my suggestion as an answer assuming (according to your last comment) that all the views that are visible are arranged by the stack view and what you want to do is to add one more view at the top of the stack view

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add the view at the top of your stack view, use `stackView.insertArrangedSubview(newView, at:0)`

Comment: StackView is one of the three UIViews

Comment: So which are other 2 views? And why they can't be also arranged by the stack view?

Comment: You alright, but this is my first app, so I made like this, and now I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up your screen with your "put other view here" in place, and a fixed height constraint on that view. Make the views below have a fixed space to the bottom of the "other view here view."

Then control-drag from the "put other view here"'s height constraint into your view controller. This will make the constraint an outlet.

Now edit the height constraint and set it's constant to 0. This will collapse that view to 0 height, causing it to disappear, and the other views to shift up.

Then, in code, when you want the "other view here" view to show up, use the outlet to set the constant on that view back to it's previous non-zero value, and then call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the parent view to update the view layouts based on changed constraints.

You could also write code that would insert your "other view here" view into the view hierarchy, but that would involve removing constraints and adding constraints in code, which is a bit of a pain.

By adjusting the height constraint on the view you can show/hide it back and forth with very little effort.